# Обработка и хранение пользовательских условий

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

## Доброго времени суток, нужна помощь в реализации набора пользовательских условий.

Есть список полей (field1, field2, field3), операторов (=, !=, <, >, in, not in) и логических операторов ( &&, ||) и пользователь может сформировать из них любое уловие.
Например.
`field1 = 100 || field2 not in a,b,c && field3 > 500`
Весь глубокий смыл объяснить трудно, но можно ориентироваться на работу фильтров. Клиент его составляет, на сервере он обрабатывается и отдает соответствующий пользовательскому условию результат.

Также это условие необходимо хранить в базе.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался?
Может готовое решение?
Или хорошие практики?

Comment: но какая тут проблема? по сути все просто - формируем условие, берем от него md5, сохраняем в таблицу, где md5 === primaryKey, вот и вся кухня, работать будет моментально

Comment: Вот есть проект ( https://github.com/ralphschindler/basic-query-filter ) который может вам пригодится